# How to show empty data row in gridview control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here I am working with gridview here is the gidview binding

```
conn = new SqlConnection(strconnection);
string squery = "sql query";

da = new SqlDataAdapter(squery, conn);
ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "tbl1");

GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

This the gridview control asp code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="None" 
     HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid_header" 
     RowStyle-CssClass="grid_item" 
     RowStyle-Height="30px"  
     AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="775px" EmptyDataText="Empty">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Order Code" DataField="ordercode" 
           HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
           ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Transation Code" DataField="transcode"  
           HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
           ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Plan Name" DataField="product" 
           HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
           ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Plan Started" DataField="Start_d" 
           HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
           ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Plan Ending" DataField="End_d" 
           HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
           ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="Payed" DataField="Payed" 
           HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
           ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Pay Date" DataField="PayDate" 
           HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
           ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Payed Amt" DataField="amtpaid" 
           HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
           ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Pay Amt" DataField="PayAmount" 
           HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
           ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is result emp like this

```
 Header1 header2 header3 header4 
     1       asdas   22sdas  asdasda
     2       sasa             asdasas
     3       asdas  
     4                         asdasas
```

like this result

Here my problem is I want show the NULL places just show the "EMPTY" Message. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `NullDisplayText="EMPTY"` [NullDisplayText Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.nulldisplaytext.aspx)

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="transcode"
        NullDisplayText="EMPTY"
        HeaderText="header2"/>
```

If what is coming from your DB is not `NULL` but an empty string, you will need to use template field

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="header2">
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Eval("transcode").ToString() == "" ? "EMPTY" : Eval("transcode").ToString() %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: thanks for answering nice sir working ...if i want change the empty font color how it is

Comment: That could be complex: 1) Do it from code-behind in the `RowDataBound` event of the GridView and set the CssClass based on if empty or not 2) enable html encode/decode on the BoundField and use `"<span style='color:red'">EMPTY</span>"`. GridView does not interpret html by default - check that out

Answer (score 3):

Check out [`BoundField.NullDisplayText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.nulldisplaytext.aspx)

> Gets or sets the caption displayed for a field when the field's value
> is null.

---

Sometimes a field's value is stored as `null` in the data source. You can specify a custom caption to display for fields that have a `null` value by setting the `NullDisplayText` property.

In your case, you can use it like;

```
<asp:BoundField NullDisplayText="EMPTY" HeaderText="Order Code" DataField="ordercode" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  />
```

Since you didn't write your sql query, as an alternative, you can use [`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) functions for your columns.

> Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.

For example;

```
SELECT ISNULL(Column1, "EMPTY")
```

Since you asked, *How to change null text color?* You can use [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event for this process. For example;

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>

protected void RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       // Use for loop for based all rows.
       if(e.Row.Cells[i].Text == "EMPTY")
                e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.Red;         
    }
}
```

Comment: how to change null text color

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add :

```
NullDisplayText="Empty"
```

Like:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Order Code" DataField="ordercode" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" NullDisplayText="Empty" />
```

Comment: how to change null test color