# How to accept null value in GridView from C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a table in my database which passes:

- **RewardAmountID**
- **Start_Date**
- **End_Date**
- **Reward_Amount**

back to my code behind. **End_Date** can be null but for some reason when i am running my code i am getting an error.

```
Cannot set Column 'END_DATE' to be null. Please use DBNull instead.
```

Here is my C# Code.

```
Amounts = ser.GetRewardAmounts().ToList();

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("REWARD_AMOUNT_ID", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("START_DATE", typeof(DateTime)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("END_DATE", typeof(DateTime)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("REWARD_AMOUNT", typeof(decimal)));

    foreach (var item in Amounts)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr[0] = item.REWARD_AMOUNT_ID;
        dr[1] = item.START_DATE;
        dr[2] = item.END_DATE;
        dr[3] = item.REWARD_AMOUNT;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);

    dg_amounts.DataSource = dv;
    dg_amounts.DataBind();
```

If anyone has any information on this issue, your help would be great!

Comment: what is DCRA in the foreach? seems like it should be item?

Comment: @IsThatSo You are correct I have only just realised that thanks alot!

Comment: Actually this has nothing to do with asp.net and grid view, but with ADO.NET. I have fixed the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Actually all the information you need is already in the exception message - you are obviously trying to set a `null` value to a `DataColumn`. The problem is that `DataColumn` doesn't use nulls, but `DBNull`. So you could do it like this:

```
dr[2] = DCRA.END_DATE ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! I knew i had to allow it null somewhere. I tried adding AllowNulls to my GridView and it didnt work. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to say if its Null dont display anything in the datagrid for that cell?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218714/how-to-show-empty-data-row-in-gridview-control for displaying null in DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this property to handle null values into grid.

Property : nulldisplaytext="xxx"